# Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>' Ionic 4

Tags: angular, api, observable, ionic4

I am currently working with Google API with Ionic 4, I am trying to implement a method that takes an address in entry and returns the latitude and longitude of this address(geocoding). 
When thrying to implement that method, I had this issue:

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable':

The function code:

```
geocodeAddress(location: string): Observable<Location> {
  return this.waitForMapsToLoad().pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return new Observable(Location => {
      this.geocoder.geocode({address: location}, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          observer.next({
            lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
          observer.next({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  })
);
}`
```

Location class:

```
export interface Location {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
```

Imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { filter, catchError, tap, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { Location } from './Position';
```

Error generated:

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<Location>'.   
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from 
type 'Location': lat, lng
```

I saw people having this kind of problem but not the same one, could you please help me ?

Comment: Put your code in the question instead of images

Comment: Post your imports as well.

Comment: What happens if you change the code to `return new Observable<Location>(`?
This should either help TS infer the correct type, or will at least show a more detailed error message.

Comment: I changed my post as you guys asked me, could you please help me ?

Comment: @bryan60 done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are missing some type for some value, and the compiler cannot figure out the type of your observable.

Mention it explicitely using `new Observable<Location>`, which should point you further to another type mismatch error, or cast your observable using

```
return new Observable(Location => {
  this.geocoder.geocode({address: location}, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      observer.next({
        lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
      observer.next({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
    }
    observer.complete();
  });
}) as Observable<Location>;
```

Using explicit typings, you can narrow down to the line posing problem, and apply your cast to this line only.

edit: By copy/pasting your code, I noticed you use `Location` as your lambda variable, I assume its an error you made while posting, and that it is correctly set to `observer` in your code.